# DCHP server on virtual machine in HNVv1 virtual network

Tags: windows, networking, powershell, hyper-v, dhcp

I've got a virtual machine with Windows Server 2016 Datacenter, Hyper-V nested virtualization on the host operating system switched on for this virtual machine and Hyper-V role installed on it.

```
PS C:\> Set-VMProcessor -VMName hvm -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

```
PS C:\> Install-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V -IncludeManagementTools -Restart
```

Two more virtual machines (nested) with Debian Linux are deployed on this virtual machine. I'm trying to set up a local network between these two VMs using Hyper-V Network Virtualization (according to documentation, it's called HNVv1). HNVv1 configured as follows:

```
PS C:\> Get-NetVirtualizationProviderAddress
ProviderAddress  : 192.168.1.2
InterfaceIndex   : 5
PrefixLength     : 24
VlanID           : 0
AddressState     : Preferred
MACAddress       : XXXXXXXXXXXX
ManagedByCluster : False

PS C:\> Get-NetVirtualizationProviderRoute
InterfaceIndex    : 5
DestinationPrefix : 0.0.0.0/0
NextHop           : 192.168.1.1
Metric            : 0

PS C:\> Get-NetVirtualizationCustomerRoute
RoutingDomainID   : {9CC4A292-A1C6-41DF-A4ED-4C78F850E682}
VirtualSubnetID   : 4101
DestinationPrefix : 192.168.46.0/24
NextHop           : 0.0.0.0
Metric            : 255

PS C:\> Get-NetVirtualizationLookupRecord
CustomerAddress : 192.168.46.2
VirtualSubnetID : 4101
MACAddress      : 00155d5d2a02
ProviderAddress : 192.168.1.2
Rule            : TranslationMethodEncap
VMName          :
UseVmMACAddress : False
Type            : Dynamic

CustomerAddress : 0.0.0.0
VirtualSubnetID : 4101
MACAddress      : 00155d5d2a02
ProviderAddress : 192.168.1.2
Rule            : TranslationMethodEncap
VMName          : vm01
UseVmMACAddress : False
Type            : L2Only

CustomerAddress : 0.0.0.0
VirtualSubnetID : 4101
MACAddress      : 00155d5d2a03
ProviderAddress : 192.168.1.2
Rule            : TranslationMethodEncap
VMName          : vm02
UseVmMACAddress : False
Type            : L2Only
```

Each nested virtual machine has two virtual network adapters:

```
VMName SwitchName VirtualSubnetId MacAddress   DhcpGuard RouterGuard
------ ---------- --------------- ----------   --------- -----------
vm01   vs01                     0 00155D5D2A00       Off         Off
vm01   vs01                  4101 00155D5D2A02       Off         Off
vm02   vs01                     0 00155D5D2A01       Off         Off
vm02   vs01                  4101 00155D5D2A03       Off         Off
```

Adapters with MAC addresses 00155D5D2A00 and 00155D5D2A01 have static IP addresses 192.168.1.3 and 192.168.1.4 respectively and use for ssh, further not of interest.

Virtual machine vm01 has static IP address 192.168.46.2 that learned by Hyper-V as expected (Dynamic LookupRecord). Also, isc-dhcp-server installed on vm01. It's configured to offer addresses from subnet 192.168.46.0/24 on eth1 (00155D5D2A02).

```
root@vm01:~# tail -n 4 /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
subnet 192.168.46.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 192.168.46.10 192.168.46.50;
        # option routers 192.168.46.1;
}
```

```
root@vm01:~# tcpdump -e -n -i eth1
17:20:28.909319 00:15:5d:5d:2a:03 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:15:5d:5d:2a:03, length 300
17:20:28.909603 00:15:5d:5d:2a:02 > 00:15:5d:5d:2a:03, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 192.168.46.2.67 > 192.168.46.10.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300
17:20:30.180282 00:15:5d:5d:2a:03 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:15:5d:5d:2a:03, length 300
17:20:30.180496 00:15:5d:5d:2a:02 > 00:15:5d:5d:2a:03, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 192.168.46.2.67 > 192.168.46.10.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300
```

```
root@vm02:~# tcpdump -e -n -i eth1
17:20:28.898397 00:15:5d:5d:2a:03 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:15:5d:5d:2a:03, length 300
17:20:30.185906 00:15:5d:5d:2a:03 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:15:5d:5d:2a:03, length 300
```

So my question is why the DHCP response not getting through? This response doesn't match L2Only LookupRecord? If I manually add static LookupRecord with MAC address 00:15:5d:5d:2a:03 and customer IP address 192.168.46.10, vm02 can see the DHCP reply and setup offered IP address, but, obviously, this not what I'm waiting for. I just need working DHCP in virtual local network and need Hyper-V to automatically collect addresses received from DHCP. Microsoft documentation about HNVv1 mentions that this technology can do such things and L2Only LookupRecord was added especially for this purpose.